# How to read in an id element that has an href

Tags: javascript, html, href

I am trying to remove the content referenced by the following id:

```
<...id href="https://xyz'...>
```

My code:

```
var right = document.getElementById('https://xyz');
var parent = right.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(right);
```

The problem is when I reference the name of the id, it comes back as null. I tried document.getElementById('https://xyz').href, yet still null. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: this is wrong html code, `...` is not a valid tag and id as no value

Comment: I agree with the wrong html code but also you get null because you only have `id`
If you try to get it using the `href` then you will get what you want

Comment: `<a href="http://someLink" id="someID"/>` and then using javascript, `var right = document.getElementById('someId');` This should get you there. Also, please read the MDN docs for this stuff in the future. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
var right = document.querySelector('[href="https://xyz"]');
```

---

or if you need the `n-th` match, [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var right = document.querySelectorAll('[href="https://xyz"]')[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` as the name suggests, selects an element by id so you have to define an id on your element: `id="some_id"` and then in JavaScript `document.getElementById('some_id')`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you did not assign any ID to that tag. So document.getElementById('https://xyz') won't give you anything because there is no tag with this ID.

You have to assign an ID like this:

```
<...id="ID_of_href" href="https://xyz'...>
```

Then you can get it with:

```
document.getElementById('ID_of_href')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all we got to understand what is the html id attribute.

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value
>   must be unique within the HTML document).
>
> The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet,
>   and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with
>   the specific id.

According to this link: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp.

W3schools is a great web site for you to learn web development.

**How to achieve your purpose:**

```js
const barElement = document.getElementById('bar');//Getting the element which id is bar.
console.log(barElement);
const fooElement = barElement.parentNode;//Getting bars parent.
console.log(fooElement);
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <a id="bar" href="#"></a>
</div>
```